# Custom camera app not saving image

Tags: android, android-camera

I've put this code together based on Google's camera guide. Camera app works, but noting happens on button click. Maybe noting should happen, I'm just getting to know Camera API but I suppose it should save image on SD card but nothing is there. Do I missing something in this code:

```
public class NewItemCamera extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private NewItemSurfaceView mPreview;
Button captureButton;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.al_newitem_camera);

    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new NewItemSurfaceView(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flCamera);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

        }
    });
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("Camera error",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

Comment: No Errors in logcat?

Comment: I cant use logcat, because I'm at work and my laptop is not recognizing my phone for some reason. I transfer apk on phone and test it that way. Button click is not crashing app so I suppose no major error exists.

Comment: Better put up a decent development environment or it'll grow you a lot of grey hair. It will take you ages to figure out why something does **not** happen without logging. Of course it does not Crash - you swallow all exceptions and write them to logcat. Which would be ok if you could read the logcat.

Comment: Ok Fildor, thx. I'll try it when I get home. Btw I've installed genymotion emulator and tried it with it. It works ok, images are saved. And you got the point about swallowing exceptions, still android noob, sorry :)

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
private String imgPath;

private void selectImage() {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ProfileActivity.this);
    // builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] { "Take a Photo",
            "Choose from Gallery" },
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                setImageUri());
                        startActivityForResult(intent1, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
                                PICK_IMAGE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}


 public Uri setImageUri() {

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
return imgUri;
 }


  public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
 }
```

onActivityForResultSetMethod

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
        System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));

    } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
        selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
        System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));


    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
  }
 }


 public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
 try {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
    // 2.
    int scale = 1;
    while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
 }


public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
} else
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why he should "try this"?

Comment: its work for me to take photo from camera and save in sdcard and get path of that photo..

Comment: Your solution does not include a custom camera app. This is using an existing app which really has nothing to do with the OP's question.